# CSS table - different color for the first td element of a table, striped

Tags: css

I manage to have striped rows, I also manage to color only the first element of a table, but i don't manage to do both at the same time!

Here is my code:

```
.raceresultscss>tbody>tr>td:first-child:nth-of-type(even){
    background-color:black !important;
    color:white;
}

.raceresultscss>tbody>tr>td:first-child:nth-of-type(odd){
    background-color:#94c946 !important;
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: what do you trying to do? It's not oblivious from question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this `.raceresultscss>tbody>tr>td:first-child:nth-of-type(even)` doesn't exist.. the first child is always odd...

Did you mean like that?

```css
.raceresultscss>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(even)>td:first-child{
    background-color:black !important;
    color:white;
}

.raceresultscss>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(odd)>td:first-child{
    background-color:#94c946 !important;
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<table class="raceresultscss">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td><td>A1</td><td>B1</td><td>C1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td><td>A2</td><td>B2</td><td>C2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td><td>A3</td><td>B3</td><td>C3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! it's perfect

Answer (score 1):

Even rows + first cell highlight.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
  height: 3rem;
  border: yellow 1px dashed;
}

table tr:nth-child(odd) td:first-child {
  background-color: green !important;
}

table tr:nth-child(even) td:first-child {
  background-color: blue !important;
}

table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```